# how to use Smarty to return Database elements

Tags: php, database, smarty

I feel like this is something really simple that I'm just not seeing.

In a Smarty template, I'm trying to return a value from one table based on finding its key in another. In this case, given the campaign id in the Event table `{$event.campaign_id}`, I want to return the corresponding Campaign Name which is stored in the Campaign Table `{$campaign.name}`.

Unfortunately I'm drawing blanks, and apparently asking google all the wrong questions.

Comment: Smarty is a template engine should not be used for database operation. So first prepare Your variables in module / class and the pass them to smarty for displaying.